# Does Scriptaculous have a no-conflict mode?

Tags: jquery, scriptaculous

I'm inheriting some code that used Scriptaculous.  They want to move over to jQuery.  I plan to leave the code that is already written in Scriptaculous alone and write any new code in jQuery.

I know that I can use the no-conflict mode in jQuery to handle conflicts.  Does Scriptaculous have a no-conflict mode or something similar so I can use the $ with jQuery and a non $ marker with Scriptaculous?

Comment: ahh, script.aculo.us  that takes me back.

Comment: Not that I know of, no.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer : No
So you have to use jquery in noconflict mode.

[Scriptaculous is no more being updated](https://github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/issues/42)